# How to prevent from firebase auth to change user provider - flutter firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm creating a flutter app with firebase.
I've added as one of my auth method, google sign in.
But if I register with the same email with an email and password,
and then sign in via google with the same email, firebase will change the provider of the user from email and password to google and when you'll try to login with email and password, the older password will not be vaild any more and you'll have to go through a password reset process.
How can I prevent firebase from changing the user provider?? Or how can check if this email is already registed in my firebase project (with the same email of course)???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under authentication -> sign in methods
Activate: One account per email address.

[image]

[image]